# Replace two characters with sed dynamically

Tags: unix, sed, replace

I have the following strings

```
C:/data
D:/backups
C:/Users/Guest/old_data
F:/files/new
```

How can I replace the first two characters with `/cygdrive/LOWERCASE_DRIVE_LETTER`?

**RESULT**

```
/cygdrive/c/data
/cygdrive/d/backups
/cygdrive/c/Users/Guest/old_data
/cygdrive/f/files/new
```

Comment: Please always try to add your efforts in your post too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.\):/\/cygdrive\/\l\1/' file
```

Remember by grouping the first character followed by a `:`. Then insert `/cygdrive/` and lowercase the group i.e. the first character.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F':' 'sub(/../,"/cygdrive/"tolower($1))' file
```

Brief explanation,

- `-F':'`: set ':' as the field separator.
- `tolower($1)`: return thee lower case of $1
- `sub(/../,"/cygdrive/"tolower($1))`: substitute the first 2 character to **"/cygdrive/"tolower($1)**

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{sub(/:/,"",$1);$1=tolower($1);print "/cygdrive/" $0}' Input_file
```